# Plot 1 row for multiple datasets using the same x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm struggling to plot my data on separate graphs (one graph, 1 line) and give them an appropriate "name" as a label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

d = pd.DataFrame({'Time_min': [1, 2, 3], 
                    'A1': [1000, 2000, 1000], 
                    'A12': [2000, 3000, 2000], 
                    'B12': [3000, 5000, 3000]})

template = pd.DataFrame({'well_id': ['A1', 'A12', 'B12'],
                         'name': ['Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample4']})

df1 = pd.merge(template, d.T, how='left', left_on='well_id', right_index=True)
df2 = df1.iloc[:,2:].T

print(d.head())
print(df1.head())

#for index, row in df2.iterrows():

plt.figure()
plt.plot(d.Time_min, df2, label = df1.iloc[:,1])
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

In the end I want each of my graphs to look like this:

```
plt.plot(d.Time_min, d['A12'], label = df1.iloc[1,1])
```

But without specifying exact sample and it's label (name) visualized on the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what output I'm expecting, but the following code can be used to achieve a graph that arranges 'Time_min' on the x-axis in ID units. Does this fit the intent of your question?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

d = pd.DataFrame({'Time_min': [1, 2, 3], 
                    'A1': [1000, 2000, 1000], 
                    'A12': [2000, 3000, 2000], 
                    'B12': [3000, 5000, 3000]})

template = pd.DataFrame({'well_id': ['A1', 'A12', 'B12'],
                         'name': ['Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample4']})

df1 = pd.merge(template, d.T, how='left', left_on='well_id', right_index=True)
df1.columns = ['well_id', 'name', 'Time_min_1', 'Time_min_2','Time_min_3']

df1.plot(x='well_id', kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I added the code to show how I want my output to look like.

Comment: I've run the updated code and added a graph, is this graph what you're looking for? The expected graph is not clear to me.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the type of graph I'm looking for. It's straightforward to make it for 1 graph, for every sample with the correct label, without specifying it manually. I just can't figure out how to use for? loop? functions to achieve that.